# Commons with Multiple Vendor

Tags: webpack

I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong when it comes to using webpack's libarary output.

entry point looks like:

```
entry: {
  app1: './app1.js'
  app2: './app2.js',
  app3: './app3.js
  vendor: [
     'jQuery',
     'moment'
  ],
  vendorReact: [
     'react',
     'redux'
  ]
},
```

app1 use jquery and moment.

app2 use jquery, moment, react, and, redux.

app3 use jquery

**what i want is:**
when go to app1. index.html will be like this :

```
script src vendor.js
script src commons.js //commons between app1.js and app2.js
script src app1.js
```

go to app2. index.html will be like this :

```
script src vendor.js
script src vendorReact.js
script src commons.js //commons between app1.js and app2.js
script src app2.js
```

go to app3. index.html will be like this :

```
script src app3.js
```

my webpack.config.js looks like:

```js
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack');
   
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app1: './app1.js',
    app2: './app2.js',
    app3: './app3.js',
    vendor: [
      'jquery',
      'moment'
    ],
    vendorReact: [
      'react',
      'redux'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist/js/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react'],
          compact: false
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'commons',
      chunks: ['app1', 'app2']
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      chunks: ['commons', 'app1', 'app2']
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendorReact',
      chunks: ['commons', 'app1', 'app2']
    })
  ]
};
```

**expecting result:**

```
    vendor: -webpack runtime
            -jQuery
            -moment
    vendorReact: -react
                 -redux
    commons: commons file between app1 and app2
    app1: app1 (without commons file between app1 and app2)
    app2: app2 (without commons file between app1 and app2)
    app3: -webpack runtime
          -app3 (contains jQuery)
```

if use this practise example github: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/two-explicit-vendor-chunks

the jquery plugin in app3 move to vendor too. and i dont want like that.

what am i missing here?